# Match a special utf8 character regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How Do I match a special sign in regex?

```
– is not the same as -; – is longer and seems to have a different character code
```

I did not think of testing for the special character.

Example string I need to check:

```
Testshop – Best fan ware | Example shop
```

Should return

```
Testshop
```

The regex I use:

```
/[^\|\-\;\–]*/
```

However it does not return the correct result. The problem is the – character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is unnecessary except for `-` (dash).

```
>> 'Testshop – Best fan ware | Example shop'[/[^|\-;–]*/]
=> "Testshop "
```

If you want only alpha-numeric chracter, use `\w+` (*also match `_`*):

```
>> 'Testshop – Best fan ware | Example shop'[/\w+/]
=> "Testshop"
```